# IntelliJ replace text with tag

Tags: html, regex, intellij-idea, webstorm

I need to replace some html file names in my html file with anchor tags, such that:

```
abc.html
file.html
```

becomes:

```html
<a href="abc.html">abc.html </a>
<a href="file.html">file.html </a>
```

I have though of the following regex in `find`: `[a-z-0-9]+\.html` and it seems to work, but I don't know what to add in `replace`. I have tried some answers from here , but they did not work. Can you please help?

[image: Image reference]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [capturing groups](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference), that then you can refer back to in the replace box..

Capture groups are created adding parenthesis to `find`: `([a-z-0-9]+\.html)`

Then `replace` would be: `<a href="$1">$1 </a>`

`$1` means the first capture group.